# How to overlay a directory tree on filesystem in buildroot?

Tags: filesystems, overlay, embedded-linux, yocto, buildroot

I need to run benchmarks, for which I need to copy a directory tree that contains the compiled binaries and data that I have compiled on my host. I need this directory tree to be available when I log into buildroot.
At present I am at a state where I can log into root but the root file system contains nothing application specific from me (shows empty).
What is the right way to do it ? The information in buildroot document is in pieces and there is no clear working example available. Can anyone help with an example ?  Can anyone please address the paths of the directory tree if relevant and any sizes that need to be taken care of ? Thanks

Comment: Use the `BR2_ROOTFS_OVERLAY` config option. Read the 'Customizing the generated target filesystem' section in the [manual](https://buildroot.org/downloads/manual/manual.html)